# onSubmit not work on react.js use Formik and refresh the site

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik

I'm using `Formik` for validation form in React.js project but unfortunately it's not work and when i cleck to submit button hole the will be refreshed...

```
<Formik initialValues = {{
            email: 'test@test.com',
            password: '',
            tags: [],
            date: null,
            state: {value: 'reasonml', label: 'ReasonML'}
        }}
validationSchema = {
    SignupSchema
}
onSubmit = {
    this.handleSubmit
} > {
    ({
        handleSubmit,
        setFieldValue,
        setFieldTouched,
        handleChange,
        handleBlur,
        values,
        errors,
        touched,
        isSubmitting
    }) => (
        <Form >
            <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                <Label><IntlMessages id="forms.email"/></Label>
                <Field className="form-control" name="email"/> {errors.email && touched.email
                    ? (
                        <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">{errors.email}</div>
                    )
                    : null}
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                <Label><IntlMessages id="forms.password"/></Label>
                <Field className="form-control" name="password" type="password"/> {errors.password && touched.password
                    ? (
                        <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">{errors.password}</div>
                    )
                    : null}
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                <Label className="d-block"><IntlMessages id="form-components.tags"/></Label>
                <FormikTagsInput
                    name="tags"
                    value={values.tags}
                    onChange={setFieldValue}
                    onBlur={setFieldTouched}/> {errors.tags && touched.tags
                    ? (
                        <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">{errors.tags}</div>
                    )
                    : null}
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                <Label className="d-block"><IntlMessages id="form-components.date"/></Label>
                <FormikDatePicker
                    name="date"
                    value={values.date}
                    onChange={setFieldValue}
                    onBlur={setFieldTouched}/> {errors.date && touched.date
                    ? (
                        <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">{errors.date}</div>
                    )
                    : null}
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup className="form-group has-float-label">
                <Label><IntlMessages id="forms.state"/></Label>
                <FormikReactSelect
                    name="state"
                    id="state"
                    value={values.state}
                    options={options}
                    onChange={setFieldValue}
                    onBlur={setFieldTouched}/> {errors.state && touched.state
                    ? (
                        <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">{errors.state}</div>
                    )
                    : null}
            </FormGroup>
            <Button color="primary" type="submit">Submit</Button>
        </Form>
    )
}
```

its schema that I used:

```
const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string()
        .email('Invalid email address')
        .required('Email is required!'),
    password: Yup.string()
        .required('Password is required!'),
    tags: Yup.array()
        .min(3, 'Pick at least 3 tags')
        .required("At least one tag is required"),
    date: Yup.date()
        .nullable()
        .required("Date required"),
    state: Yup.object().shape({
        label: Yup.string().required(),
        value: Yup.string().required(),
    })
        .nullable()
        .required('State is required!'),
})
```

and its handlesubmit method:

```
    handleSubmit = (values, {setSubmitting}) => {

        const payload = {
            ...values,
            state: values.state.value,
        };
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2))
            setSubmitting(false);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

In this formik form, onSubmit function not working. I dont know why? Please tell me guys what is problem with my code?

Comment: Can you add a codesandbox??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `handleSubmit` in form and `isSubmitting` in submit button

```
<Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onCheckCodeFunction}>
                {({...,handleSubmit,isSubmitting}) => (
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                         ...
                  
                           <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}> 
                            Submit 
                           </button> 
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and the reason was that I was importing the component 'Form' from 'reacstrap' (another library) and not from 'Formik'.

Comment: I think you should ask to @Hamed Rahmani, in what way the Form imported, or at least write that part of the code, to suggest that solution later, because at the moment you are not sure if that is the problem, then there is no way that is the safe solution.

Comment: I think this is better suited a comment. However that does **not** mean that your answer is NAA.